# Date is not saving the correct value in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, date

I am currently developing a request page that gets the current date. At first it was working fine and saving the right value into the database, but after I added a code which gets today's week number, the value being saved in my req_date field becomes 0000-00-00. Please help

```js
<?php
$req_date = $_POST['req_date'];

$ddate = date("Y-m-d");
$duedt = explode("-", $ddate);
$date  = mktime(0, 0, 0, $duedt[1], $duedt[2], $duedt[0]);
$week  = (int)date('W', $date);
      
   $sql = "INSERT INTO ops (req_date, week)
            VALUES ('$req_date', '$week')"; 
?>
```

```html
<td>REQUEST_DATE: </td>
<td><input type="date" name="req_date" value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>'></td>
```

Comment: Are you printing out the date before you post is as a query? Also, from the looks of it, you're not sanitizing the input which makes you highly susceptible to SQL injection. And finally, is your DB field assigned a date? It might not be matching the format the field requires

Comment: Please edit your question ans add the schema of the table **ops**. Also, your code is subject to SQL injection. Use either PDO or mysqli with bound varibles instead of building the query directly.

Comment: Yes, I am printing out the date before post as a query. The database field is assigned as a date @SterlingArcher

Comment: There is nothing in your code that is problamatic, which would suggest that `$_POST['req_date']` contains an incorrect date format for your database field

Comment: @Jeemusu it is set to a date field

Comment: if your do a `print_r($_POST['req_date']);die();` at the top of your code what is the output?

Comment: I did vardump, its getting the textbox value which is the date but is being saved in the database as 0000-00-00 @Jeemusu

Comment: What was that value from the textbox?

Comment: @Jeemusu The current date 
<input type="date" name="req_date" value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>'>

Comment: Perhaps Your form date box has a format of YYYY-dd-mm and your database table field has a format YYY-mm-dd and at saving, the value is out of range and your database insert 0000-00-00

Comment: Check your Chrome format can be YYYY-dd-mm. Your Chrome browser has a datepicker that by default hast YYYY-dd-mm and your database table field has YYYY-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

**Chrome can put this format** you have to try to use another datepicker set the default format.

[image: Screenshot]

This can be a problem if you have a table field with format **YYYY-mm-dd** and you use that code. You need to improve your code firstly.